# Cast a Hex String to varbinary in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let say I have a `varchar(100)` call `@hexString` and I

```
SET @hexString ='0x47617279204a6f686e736f6e2032303230'
```

How do I cast this varchar to an actual hexidecimal `0x47617279204a6f686e736f6e2032303230`(without the quotation mark)?

Comment: when you select this it wont show quotation mark

Comment: @mohan111 I know but I want to "cast" this varchar to a varbinary, like an actual sequence of hex numbers, instead of a string.

Comment: You want to cast that text without the presence of qoutation mark?

Answer (score 5):

Use `CONVERT` with a "style" value of `1`:

```
DECLARE @HexString VARCHAR(100);
SET @HexString = '0x47617279204a6f686e736f6e2032303230';

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(100), @HexString, 1);
```

The "style" value is an optional 3rd parameter to the `CONVERT` function.

That returns the following as a `VARBINARY` type, not a string:

```
0x47617279204A6F686E736F6E2032303230
```